# SVN manage multiple versions of the same project

Tags: svn, web-applications, version-control

I am trying to set up an SVN system for my company but the structure is bit complicated and I am not sure if it is achievable. 
So the scenario is this. We are developing a web application (not a normal website but a complex app) and we have 2 different groups working:

1. Normal developers handling bug fixed.
2. Special developers responsible for R&D work.

The R&D team is developing some new functionalities which use some existing classes and also generates some different classes of its own. Now the Normal developers are outsourced and shouldn't be able to access any of the files the R&D group creates until it is released to the public but R&D group should have access to all the changes the first team makes.

Is it possible to handle this? If so how?

Comment: I would probably look into some Enterprise Git solution with access control/organizations and teams

Comment: @information_interchange the question is about [svn] and not [git].

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to set up an SVN system for my company but the structure
>   is bit complicated and I am not sure if it is achievable.

It is achievable. However, you should find out the detailed requirements that will cover your scenario. The current scenario could be backed by several approaches.

You should design a [branching strategy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.html) for your development process and make use of [path-based authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) to implement access control in your SVN repository. It will help you set up the permissions granularly in a fashion that R&D has full access to the project's history, but outsourced developers have a limited access.